# Handle the controls inside WPF User Control using WPF UI Automation

Tags: c#, wpf, ui-automation

I am trying to handle a user control through WPF UI Automation,

I am unable to traverse through the User Control. Only able to traverse through the window where User Control is being consumed. Please suggest how can I work and get the handle of WPF user controls elements.

I am trying to handle through a windows application, I am following below code but it always returns null,

```
AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.RootElement;
if (rootElement != null)
{
    AutomationElement expander = appElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Expander Name"));
    AutomationElement expander = appElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIDProperty, "expID"));
}
```

The Expander in the user is written below,

```
       <UserControl x:Class="UCCustomerInfo.CustInfo"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:my2="clr-namespace:MyDatePicker;assembly=MyDatePicker"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Height="Auto" 
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:UCCustomerInfo" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/BFETH-CustomerMT;component/Resource/Resource-LinearGradientBrush.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/BFETH-CustomerMT;component/Resource/Resource-Control.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/BFETH-CustomerMT;component/Resource/SBFEResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>



<Expander Style="{x:Null}"  FontSize="16" Header="By num" Height="Auto" Name="byNum" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                Margin="3,10,0,0" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#4E87D4" IsExpanded="False" >
            <Border Name="borderRMno" Margin="20,0,13,0" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="3"
                                BorderBrush="#ADD8E6" Background="#DFEFF0">
                <Grid Name="GridRMLPbyRMNo" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,5,0,5">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Name="Custo_No" Content="Cust No" Margin="0,4" 
                    Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    <TextBox Name="Cust_Search" Width="120" Height="26" 
                                     MaxLength="14" 
                                    Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,3" HorizontalAlignment="left" 

                                    TabIndex="11" 
                                   />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Expander>
```

Comment: Do you have a usercontrol source code?

Comment: Please see the edit